# Minipages parallel with included image

Tags: floats, minipage, wrapfigure

Bonjour!

I created two columns with information using `\itemize` in two different `\minipage` environments. Now I want to include an image parallel to these two 'columns'. I tried to include the (wrapped) figure in- and outside the minipages but so far it is not working beside each other, the image will be presented underneath the minipages. Maybe it has to do with the `adjust width` environment. What are your suggestions to create three 'columns' beside each other, two with information and the third with a figure?

```
\documentclass{article}
\reversemarginpar

\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage[]{geometry}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[nochapters]{classicthesis} % Use the classicthesis style for the style of the document
\usepackage[LabelsAligned]{currvita} % Use the currvita style for the layout of the document
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx,wrapfig}
\hypersetup{colorlinks, breaklinks, urlcolor=Maroon, linkcolor=Maroon} 
\begin{document}

\begin{adjustwidth}{7.75em}{0em}
{\color{Maroon}\noindent\footnotesize\spacedallcaps{Personal Information}}\vspace{1.5pc} 
\end{adjustwidth}

\begin{adjustwidth}{-7.25em}{9em}

\begin{minipage}{0.25\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}
\setlength\itemsep{0.15em}
  \item[] \it{Nationality}
  \item[] \it{Date of Birth}
  \item[] \it{Adress}
  \item[] \it{Mail / website}
  \item[] \it{Phone}
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}%
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.575\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}
\setlength\itemsep{0.15em}
  \item[] French
  \item[] 1 august 1981, Paris (FR)
  \item[] Teststreet 1, 75013 Paris
  \item[] \href{mailto:test@test.com}{test@test.com} / \href{http://www.test.com}{www.test.com}
  \item[] 0000 00 000 000
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}
\end{adjustwidth}

\end{document}
```

Comment: please make your code compilable (complete)

Comment: minipages and images are like letters they come side by side _by default_ and only come one under the other if the line is too long, or you start a new paragraph. Impossible to guess what you did wrong as you have shown no `\includegraphics`

Answer (score 1):

This worked!

```
\documentclass{article}
\reversemarginpar

\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage[]{geometry}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[nochapters]{classicthesis} % Use the classicthesis style for the style of the document
\usepackage[LabelsAligned]{currvita} % Use the currvita style for the layout of the document
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx,wrapfig}
\hypersetup{colorlinks, breaklinks, urlcolor=Maroon, linkcolor=Maroon} 
\begin{document}

    \begin{adjustwidth}{7.75em}{0em}
{\color{Maroon}\noindent\footnotesize\spacedallcaps{Personal Information}}\vspace{1pc} 
\end{adjustwidth}

\begin{adjustwidth}{-7.75em}{-7.75em}

\begin{minipage}{0.25\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}
\setlength\itemsep{0.15em}
  \item[] \it{Nationality}
  \item[] \it{Date of Birth}
  \item[] \it{Adress}
  \item[] \it{Mail / website}
  \item[] \it{Phone}
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}%
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.65\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}
\setlength\itemsep{0.15em}
  \item[] \hspace{3.5em} French
  \item[] \hspace{3.5em} 1 august 1981, Paris (FR)
  \item[] \hspace{3.5em} Teststreet 1, 75013 Paris
  \item[] \hspace{3.5em} \href{mailto:test@test.com}{test@test.com} / \href{http://www.test.com}{www.test.com}
  \item[] \hspace{3.5em} +000 0000 0000
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\vspace{-6em}
\hspace{5em}
\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth, height=0.2\textheight]{../Pictures/test.png}
\end{minipage}
\end{adjustwidth}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that `\it{Nationality}` is wrong: it should be `\textit{Nationality}`

Answer (score 1):

You should use a `tabular`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[nochapters]{classicthesis} % Use the classicthesis style for the style of the document
\usepackage[LabelsAligned]{currvita} % Use the currvita style for the layout of the document
\usepackage{color,graphicx}

\begin{document}

\noindent\makebox[\textwidth]{%
  \hspace{-3cm}%
  \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{\hspace{3.5em}}l@{}}
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{\color{Maroon}\footnotesize\spacedallcaps{Personal Information}} \\[1pc]
  \textit{Nationality} & French \\[1ex]
  \textit{Date of Birth} & 1 august 1981, Paris (FR) \\[1ex]
  \textit{Address} & Teststreet 1, 75013 Paris \\[1ex]
  \textit{Mail} / \textit{website} &
    \href{mailto:test@test.com}{test@test.com} / \href{http://www.test.com}{www.test.com} \\[1ex]
  \textit{Phone} & +000 0000 0000
  \end{tabular}%
  \hfill
  \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}% for vertical centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth, height=0.2\textheight]{example-image}
  \end{tabular}%
  \hspace{-3cm}%
}

\end{document}
```

[image]